# enable profiler / Traceon after SQL server restart automatically

Tags: sql-server-2005

My client is facing  some deadlocks while using our application. I want to track all the deadlocks for my research and to solve the deadlocks.

i am currently run the SQL profiler for the event deadlock graph to capture the deadlock scenario.

the actual problem is that the SQL server gets restarted every day at 2 am, and the profiler stops capturing the events after the restart. by the time i come to office at start the profiler at say 10 am, there could be deadlocks which i could have missed between 2 am and 10 am. so i am looking for a way so i can capture the deadlocks without me starting manually.

i thought i could use TRACEON(1204,-1) so that the deadlock events get captured in the SQL Server error logs. But i found that the TRACE capturing too gets disabled after the restart.

Is there a way i can capture the deadlocks either by SQL profiler or by using TRACEON without me manually starting the capturing?

Nikhil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming a bit late to the party here, but you can create a stored proc that establishes your trace, and then set it to run at startup.

```
USE master;
GO

-- define the proc
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MakeMyTraceAtStartup AS
    DECLARE @TraceID INT;
    DECLARE @on BIT = 1;
    EXEC sp_trace_create @TraceID output, 6, 'c:\mypath\mytraceout.trc', 5, NULL;

    -- event 25 is a deadlock; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186265.aspx
    EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 6, @on; -- NTUserName
    EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 7, @on; -- NTDomainName
    EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 8, @on; -- HostName
    EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 10, @on; -- ApplicationName
    EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 11, @on; -- LoginName
    EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 12, @on; -- SPID
    EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 14, @on; -- StartTime
    EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 23, @on; -- Success
    EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 26, @on; -- ServerName
    EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 31, @on; -- Error
    EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 35, @on; -- DatabaseName
    EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 60, @on; -- IsSystem
    EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 64, @on; -- SessionLoginName
    -- whatever other columns you want to audit

    -- turn it on
    EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1;
GO

-- set it to run automatically at startup
EXEC sp_procoption 'usp_MakeMyTraceAtStartup', 'startup', 'true';
GO
```

Tracing is supported in SQL Server 2005 and later.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than running the trace or worrying about what is missed between those specific hours after downtime, ask the client what error the application returns. If they are at a specific area within the application you should be able to track down the statements that are causing the deadlock. Just my opinion =).

Comment: well, in this case all i get is only the victim sql and that too only the topmost sql being executed. If I get a deadlock graph, i can easily find which is the exact sql causing the deadlock. for example if a stored proc is calling another and that again calling another stored proc, where the deadlock is happening, i will get the innermost sql involved in the deadlock using the profiler, but would not get the same without them. hence i really want to get the trace out.